# Can I at least get MySQL errors to give line numbers in the correct query?

Tags: mysql, errors

We all know MySQL errors are pretty unhelpful. I understand that due to query optimisation it would be in-principle very difficult to unwind errors to their exact location in the source text and that the designers didn't bother trying.

However I'm baffled by the fact that, when I do `mysql -u foo < many_queries.sql`, the error line numbers coughed out are **not even within the correct query!** There are often *dozens* of distinct, correct queries between the reported line and the actual problem.

I assume the parser logic is roughly like this

```
for each line in source
    line_number++
    if part of last query
        append current line to last_query
    else
        if execute last_query
            yay
        else
            report error
        clear last_query
        append current line to last_query
        last query_starts_at = line_number
```

It would seem trivial for the "report error" line to at least know *where in the source the query begins* and I simply *cannot believe* that this was too difficult an engineering problem since the complexity of query execution is completely black boxed.

At the moment I'm manually commenting-out thousands of lines at a time to binary-search the problem.

**EDIT** I've noticed that the error is often reported as being in the first of the INSERT statements (although the error is caused by a trigger or a stored procedure or function being called via one of the later INSERT or UPDATE statements).

There must be a better way to *at least approximately* locate errors. What is it?

Comment: It depends on the error but I find the reporting generally very precise. The most common problem might be unmatched quotes - that means that many lines after the missing quote may be read as "inside" a string and only on next quote somewhere in the script the error may be found. Such parsing error is just not simply recoverable.

Comment: These aren't parsing errors, they're generally logical errors such as NULLs and FK type mismatches, ambiguous or duplicate names, etc etc.

Comment: In that case I am really not sure what you are talking about, because mysql executes the queries serially so it should exactly know which query is wrong.

Comment: Can you provide a short example?